# Dealing with a memory leak when cropping images in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image

I keep getting a system out of memory error when I break an image up into sub images. There's nothing too fancy going on, just splitting an image into a bunch of smaller images. Here's my code:

```
Dim counterrr As Integer = 0
Dim sorucedir As String
Dim tardir As String
sorucedir = "C:\somedir\"
tardir = "C:\otherdir\"
Dim di2 As New DirectoryInfo(sorucedir)
Dim fiArr2 As FileInfo() = di2.GetFiles()
Dim fri2 As FileInfo
Dim hh As Integer
Dim ww As Integer
hh = 995 'height of source images
ww = 1080 'width of source images
Dim sizestepX As Integer = 180
Dim stepsizeY As Integer = 239
For i = 0 To ww - 1 Step sizestepX
    For j = 0 To hh - 1 Step stepsizeY
        For Each fri2 In fiArr2
            Dim BM2 As Bitmap
            BM2 = Image.FromFile(fri2.FullName)
            ''Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
            'bm2 = Image.FromFile(fri2.FullName)
            Dim BM3 As Bitmap
            Dim rect As New Rectangle(i, j, sizestepX, stepsizeY)
            BM3 = BM2.Clone(rect, Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare)
            counterrr += 1
            Dim ss As String
            ss = tardir & counterrr & ".png"
            BM3.Save(ss, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            BM3 = Nothing
        Next
    Next
Next
```

The error comes up after creating as few as 6 images (occurs when creating the 7th image). The line where the error is thrown is this:

```
BM3 = BM2.Clone(rect, Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare)
```

How can I modify my code so they objects are correctly disposed (?) of so they don't leak memory.

Comment: Use `Using` statements... If the type implents the IDisposable interface then wrap that object up so it is properly disposed of.

Comment: @Codexer I've tried using Using both for BM2 and BM3, I still get the same error.

Comment: Also you have an array of `FileInfo` in your loop you need to pull out each object, do not create a variable to reference an object in your loop. Remove `fri2`... Also theres other suggestions but this is not code review. Your question was already answered as to what to do...

Comment: Also if you tried the `Using` statements, don't you think you should add that to your post, it is kind of important as some have just wasted their time helping you when you have already tried this. Also if you did, why does the above code not show this?

Answer (score 0):

The `Bitmap` class, along with many of the other GDI+ classes implement `IDisposable` because they hold onto underlying GDI object handles which need to be released.  Each process is limited by the OS to a maximum number of GDI objects, usually 10,000.  You can view the total number of active GDI objects per process in the Windows task manager.  To fix your problem, you need to either manually call the `Dispose` method on each `Bitamp` object you create, before it goes out of scope, or you need to wrap each `Bitmap` variable declaration in a `Using` block (so it will call `Dispose` for you).  For instance:

```
Using BM2 As Bitmap = Image.FromFile(fri2.FullName)
    Dim rect As New Rectangle(i, j, sizestepX, stepsizeY)
    Using BM3 As Bitmap = BM2.Clone(rect, Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare)
        counterrr += 1
        Dim ss As String
        ss = tardir & counterrr & ".png"
        BM3.Save(ss, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
    End Using
End Using
```

Note: there's no point in setting the `BM3` variable to `Nothing` at the end, like you're doing.  That has no bearing on anything.

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for the input - however I still get the issue! Using a copy-paste of your  code I still get the system out of memory error at image number 7!

Comment: If you that doesn't fix it, then either your problem is elsewhere in code that you haven't shown, or the problem is that they are exceptionally large images and you are running out of addressable memory (in which forcing a garbage collection may help).  Either way, there's not much we can do to help, since the code you posted isn't actually what's at fault.  How large are the images?  What's the stack trace?  What kind of memory/resource are you running out of?  Is this a 32-bit or 64-bit app?  Have you tried taking heap snapshots to compare the object counts?

Comment: @Codexer, yes, he did, but not until right before I posted my answer, so I didn't even see it.  And second, it's still a problem, even if it's not _the_ problem :)